# Asyncio script performs slowly, similar to sync script

Tags: python-asyncio

I'm writing an asyncio script to retrieve stock bars data from Interactive Brokers via the [ib_insync](https://github.com/erdewit/ib_insync) library.

While I have the script working, the performance is similar to a serial script. I was hoping to see a drastic improvement in speed. This code will be used in production.

I am new to asyncio and feel like I'm missing an important element. Below is the full script. Would very much appriciate assistance in speeding this up. Thanks.

```
import asyncio
import ib_insync as ibi
import nest_asyncio
import pandas as pd

nest_asyncio.apply()

class App:
    async def run(self, symbols):
        print(f"1 start run: {symbols}")
        self.ib = ibi.IB()
        with await self.ib.connectAsync("127.0.0.1", "****", clientId="****"):
            contracts = [ibi.Stock(symbol, "SMART", "USD") for symbol in symbols]
            bars_dict = dict()
            print(f"2 start loop: {symbols}")
            for contract in contracts:
                bars = await self.ib.reqHistoricalDataAsync(
                    contract,
                    endDateTime="",
                    durationStr="1 M",
                    barSizeSetting="1 day",
                    whatToShow="ADJUSTED_LAST",
                    useRTH=True,
                )
                # Convert to dataframes.
                bars_dict[contract.symbol] = ibi.util.df(bars)
            print(f"3 End bars: {symbols}")
            return bars_dict

    async def main(self):
        res = await asyncio.gather(self.run(self.sp500(0, 100)))
        return res

    def stop(self):
        self.ib.disconnect()

    def sp500(self, start=None, end=10):
        payload = pd.read_html(
            "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies"
        )
        first_table = payload[0]
        sp500 = first_table["Symbol"].sort_values().to_list()
        return sp500[start:end]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import time

    start = time.time()

    app = App()
    try:
        print(f"START CALL")
        res = asyncio.run(app.main())
        print(f"END CALL")
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        app.stop()
    for ticker, bars in res[0].items():
        print(f"{ticker}\n{bars}")

    print(f"Total time: {(time.time() - start)}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is running in sequence. The call to `asyncio.gather()` in `main` is useless because it is invoked with just one coroutine. You're supposed to call it with multiple coroutines to have them run in parallel.

For example, you could remove the `asyncio.gather()` from `main` (just `await self.run(self.sp500(0, 100)` there) and instead use it to parallelize calls to `reqHistoricalDataAsync`:

```
class App:
    async def run(self, symbols):
        print(f"1 start run: {symbols}")
        self.ib = ibi.IB()
        with await self.ib.connectAsync("127.0.0.1", "****", clientId="****"):
            contracts = [ibi.Stock(symbol, "SMART", "USD") for symbol in symbols]
            print(f"2 start loop: {symbols}")
            all_bars = await asyncio.gather(*[
                self.ib.reqHistoricalDataAsync(
                    contract,
                    endDateTime="",
                    durationStr="1 M",
                    barSizeSetting="1 day",
                    whatToShow="ADJUSTED_LAST",
                    useRTH=True,
                )
                for contract in contracts
            ])
            bars_dict = {}
            for contract, bars in zip(contracts, all_bars):
                # Convert to dataframes.
                bars_dict[contract.symbol] = ibi.util.df(bars)
            print(f"3 End bars: {symbols}")
            return bars_dict
```

Comment: Holy smokes, that did it!